# how do I migrate from redux to redux toolkit

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I managed to write reducer using createSlice but the action seems to be confusing.

My old reducer :

```
function listPeopleReducer(state = {
    getPeople:{}
}, action){
    switch (action.type) {
        case D.LIST_PEOPLE: {
            return {
                ...state
                , getPeople:action.payload
            }
        }
            default:{}
    }
    return state
}
```

By using createSlice from the redux toolkit, I migrated the reducer to this,

```
const listPeopleReducer = createSlice({
    initialState:{getPeople:{}},
    name:"listPeople",
    reducers:{
        listPeople(state,action){
            return {
                ...state,
                getPeople : action.payload
            } 
        }
    }
})
```

My old action, makes an api call inside it, with the help of a helper function *makeApiRequest* (which takes in parameters and returns the response of the api),

```
export function listPeople(config: any) {
    return function (dispatch: any) {
        makeApiRequest(config)
        .then((resp) => {
            dispatch({
                type :  D.LIST_PEOPLE,
                payload : resp.data
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            dispatch({
                type :  D.LIST_PEOPLE,
                payload : error
            })
        })
    }
}
```

With reduxtool kit, we could do something like,

```
const listPeople = listPeopleReducer.actions.listPeople;
```

But, how will I write my custom action that contains the helper function makeApiRequest ?
i.e The old Action should be migrated to reduxtoolkit type.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely tricky when migrating, since there are some major conceptual changes that you must eventually wrap your head around. I had to do it a couple of times before it clicked.

First, when you are creating `const listPeopleReducer` with `createSlice()`, that is not actually what you are creating. A slice is a higher level object that can [generate action creators and action types](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createslice) for you, and allows you to export reducers and actions FROM it.

Here are the changes I would make to your code:

```
const peopleSlice = createSlice({
    initialState:{getPeople:{}},
    name:"people",
    reducers:{
        listPeople(state,action){
            // uses immer under the hood so you can
            // safely mutate state here
            state.getPeople = action.payload
        }
    },
    extraReducers:
        // each thunk you create with `createAsyncThunk()` will
        // automatically have: pending/fulfilled/rejected action types
        // and you can listen for them here
        builder => 
            builder.addCase(listPeople.pending, (state,action) => {
                // e.g. state.isFetching = true
            })
            builder.addCase(listPeople.fulfilled, (state,action) => {
                // e.g. state.isFetching = false
                // result will be in action.payload
            })
            builder.addCase(listPeople.rejected, (state,action) => {
                // e.g. state.isFetching = false
                // error will be in action.payload
            })
    }
})
```

Then, outside of your slice definition, you can create actions by using `createAsyncThunk()`, and do like:

```
export const listPeople = createAsyncThunk(
    `people/list`,
    async (config, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            return makeApiRequest(config)
        } catch(error) {
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithError(error)
            // thunkAPI has access to state and includes
            // helper functions like this one
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ["Modern Redux with Redux Toolkit" page in the Redux Fundamentals docs tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) shows how to migrate from hand-written Redux logic to Redux Toolkit.

Your `makeApiRequest` function would likely be used with Redux Toolkit's `createAsyncThunk`, except that you should return the result and let `createAsyncThunk` dispatch the right actions instead of dispatching actions yourself.